# Firestore listener updates while large snapshot.get() processing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, semaphore

I am looking for some advice on an approach.  I am using firebase firestore.  I am using batch and transaction updates (depending on situation) to keep things as atomic as possible .

My application has many transactions (10's and possibly 100's of thousands).  On the user's dashboard I loop through and total some of the fields in those transactions by looping ALL transactions and totaling by user, team and challenge. Clearly, this is too costly to do each time a user hits the dashboard.  I have tried a few approaches and currently doing the following.

I store all totals in a collection.  i.e. overall totals, team totals, user totals.  These are the only items I need to fetch to show dashboard so its very minimal compared to all transactions.

I am doing all this work using firebase functions.

If I find a collection of totals does NOT exists, I create it from scratch by looping through all transactions and when done, saving results/totals to the totals collection.

I then have a firebase function firestore listener that triggers whenever a transaction changes.  Then I just update the totals based on the updated transaction so I don't need to read them all again.

The thing I worry about is that if I receive an update while the main loop/calculation is running I will lose the data for that new/updated transaction and it will cause the totals to get out of sync.

Does anyone have an idea of how to get around this issue?  Should I try and use google tasks to queue things?  Any ideas how to even keep track of if that listener is running?  Sort of like a semaphore or something (which I don't think firebase functions support).

I apologize if this is too vague.  I don't need code or anything like that, was just looking for some ideas on what would be a reasonable approach.  I

Comment: *"The thing I worry about is that if I receive an update while the main loop/calculation is running"* - please say more about this update.  Are you suggesting that there is an update to a document participating in a transaction? Is that update also within a transaction?

Comment: No updates inside the main loop for calculating totals but it does at then end - when all calculations are finished.  But it can take some time since it has to retrieve lots of records.  But after the firestore.get() starts and before it is done, transaction updates can be occur which triggers the listener.  That listener then retrieves the totals and updates them with that updated transaction.  My concern is that since main calculation loop is not done, the totals will not be correct so the change will update the "old" values in the totals document.

Comment: Essentially the transaction that comes in while the loop is still running will update the totals document before the loop has gotten to that point. Then when the calculation loop is finished, it will update the totals which would not included the transaction info that came in during the loop -it would just overwrite it.